# Qt can't find my shared library - no really it cant

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and I'm trying to implement a simple shared library for use in another application. I've read the [wiki](http://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) and other docs, but even after carefully following the steps, the compiler will always throw an error saying it can't find my header files.

I'm using Qt MinGW on Windows 10. Here's what I did:

1. Created and compiled a shared library called libgx
2. In another project (hello), added the generated liblibgx.a file, using the "Add Library" wizard.
3. Pulled my hair over this error I get when I try to include the library's header into hello's main.cpp

The wiki is not helpful here at all. It tells me, "MinGW compiled linking libraries are in .a, but you will need to add it manually (as of Qt Creator 2.7). You could also try simply linking the .dll directly cause it would probably work." I'm like WHAT?

hello's .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = hello
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp\
        C:/Users/sagar.JARVISAIO/Documents/libgx/libgx.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h\
        C:/Users/sagar.JARVISAIO/Documents/libgx/libgx.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-libgx-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/ -llibgx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-libgx-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/debug/ -llibgx
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-libgx-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/ -llibgx

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-libgx-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-libgx-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release
```

Comment: Which operating system? Please edit your question to improve it

Comment: So you tell the IDE where to find your actual library, but not where to find the header files?. Remember that building C++ applications is really a three-step process: 1. Edit; 2. Compile; 3: Link. By adding the library file you only added it to the third step, you need to tell the second step where the header files are located as well.

Comment: Do you know where the headers are that Qt is supposed to find? If so, have you told it to find them by adding the appropriate `HEADERS += path/to/header.h` directives to the `.pro` file?

Comment: Also, if you have a file ending in `.a` then it's not a shared library, it's a *static* library.

Comment: No I didn't change the .pro files because I thought the wizard is supposed to do that. Seems like the wiki could use some serious editing.

Also, the wizard only let's me select the .a file.

Comment: The wizard assumes a “properly installed” library I assume, i.e. a base folder with includes in include/, libs in lib/ etc. You added a build dir, which doesn’t contain header files (which are somewhere in the source tree in places the wizard can’t know, and often not in the required layout). Thus your INCLUDEPATH/DEPENDPATH need to point where the header files are, which is most likely not inside the build directory but the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

I manually added the headers and the library files in the .pro file using the procedure [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html). Never going to bother with that "wizard" again. It was unnecessarily adding a $$PWD variable in all my paths which I think was causing my problem.